# Spritekit ApplyImpulse jumping too high

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have my raymond node. I am applyingimpulse and the first jump is very high and the following jumps are normal.

I want the jumps to be all the same height and I have been trying heaps of stuff but still nothing works.

```
//Raymond Code
        // Raymond's Physics
    raymond.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: raymondTexture.size().width/3)
    raymond.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    raymond.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


//on Touch 
//Jump code
   if gameOver == false {
        gameoverLabel.removeFromParent()
        if jump < 3 {

            raymond.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 100))

            jump = jump + 1
        }`
```

Comment: Have you tried adding mass to the player?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
raymond.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
raymond.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 100))
```

Comment: Nothing changes, the character still jumps ridiculously high.

Comment: might be apply impulse is called multiple times in your case, check it with print or breakpoint, let us know